# Laravel Scout TNTSearch driver does not import all the data

Tags: laravel, full-text-indexing, laravel-scout

I'm trying to implement search functionality through Laravel Scout using the TNTSearch driver. Overall functionality is working but import does not index all the records in the table. For example, my table has 21 records but it just indexes around 5 records.

I see the following message on running the import command.

```
php artisan scout:import "App\Chapter_maths"
```

> Imported [App\Chapter_maths] models up to ID: 9 All
>   [App\Chapter_maths] records have been imported.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What about running "php artisan tntsearch:import App\Chapter_maths"?

Comment: I had tried this command also but same output was there so I changed the driver to mysql drivers instead of TntSearch. Now its working fine.